# Evaluate a Math Expression given in string form without using API

Tags: java, string, math

I want to evaluate an expression like `-4-12-2*12-3-4*5` given in a `String` form **without using API** as I am a beginner and want to grasp the logic.

Given below is my unsuccessful attempt to this problem which, if you may like, ignore and suggest appropriate logic.And of course your codes are also welcome :-)

```
public class SolveExpression3 {

static String testcase1 = "-4-12-2*12-3-4*5";


public static void main(String args[]){
    SolveExpression3 testInstance= new SolveExpression3();
    int result = testInstance.solve(testcase1);
    System.out.println("Result is : "+result);
}

public int solve(String str){

    int sum = 1;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    String num = "";        
    int len = str.length();
    System.out.println(str);
    for (int i = len-1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);            
        if(ch == '*')
        {
            String s = "";
            num1 = num2 = 0;
            //to get the number on left of *
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                char c = str.charAt(j);                 
                if(c == '+' || c == '-' || j == 1)
                {
                    num1 = stringToInt(s);
                    s = "";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = c + s;
                }
            }
            //to get the number on right of *
            for (int j = i; j <= len; j++)
            {
                char c = str.charAt(j);                 
                if(c == '+' || c == '-' || j == len-1)
                {
                    num2 = stringToInt(s);
                    s = "";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = c + s;
                }
            }
            sum = sum + num1*num2;

        }
        else
        {
            num = ch + num;             
        }
    }
    len = str.length();
    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(ch==' ')
        {}
        else if(ch=='+')
        {
            sum = sum + stringToInt(num);               
            num = "";
        }
        else if(ch=='-')
        {
            sum = sum - stringToInt(num);               
            num = "";
        }
        else
        {
            num = ch + num;             
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public int stringToInt(String str)
{
    int number=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int num = str.charAt(i) - 48;
        number = number*10+num;
    }
    return number;
}

}
```

Comment: @Lorenzo Baracchi: Would you focus on the main problem in hand ?

B.T.W. i have removed that portion which I included by mistake.

Comment: Even as a beginner, you should learn about *tokenization*: instead of trying to solve all your problems at once (find numbers and operators and then combine them appropriately) you should try breaking them into two problems: create one method (or class!) that reads in a string and returns a list of *tokens*, where each token is either an operator or a number. Then, write a method that reads the tokens in order, and does the right thing.

Comment: @dlev This approach of yours is OK if you're dealing with only + and - because in this manner you can calculate the expression sequentially(character by character) but when * comes you need to evaluate numbers connected by * differently !

Comment: @abhishek14d: not that you haven't specified what the problem is. You've just said that your attempt is unsuccessful.

Comment: @JBNizet You're welcome to read the code and suggest improvements.

Comment: @abhishek14d First, you said you didn't care about order of operations, so going number/operator at a time is fine. Second, tokenization is even *more* important if you do care! Parsing (which is what you're trying to do) is just way way easier if you tokenize your input properly.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this using _tokenization_ because the way I think it going is:


Step1: 4-12-2*12-3-4*5

Step2: **-8**-2*12-3-4*5

Step3: **-10** *12-3-4*5

Here I end up getting -10 against left of * operator which clearly is not desired!

Comment: @abhishek14d I don't see why that's undesired; I think the problem is under-specified, but if you really don't care about BODMAS, then -8 - 2 * 12 might as well be -10 * 12. If you do care, then you should take a step back, read up on *parsing* (and, by associated, *lexing*) and then come back and try again. It's more difficult conceptually, but it's actually *much easier* once you get it. The answer below that mentions a recursive descent parser is very much a good idea.

Comment: So if you don't care at all about BODMAS, then you should be expecting: -18 before the first multiplication, for a complete sum of -1115. Is this correct? Working purely left-to-right and evaluating every number as it arrives?

Comment: If you don't care about BODMAS it's not an evaluation of a math expression..

Comment: I apologize for wrongly specifying the problem. Now I have edited the question and desire the solution caring about BODMAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        found=true;
        static String testcase1 = "-4-12-2*12-3-4*5";
        Pattern SEGMENT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|\\D+)");
        /*\\d-means digit,
        \\.-point,
        +-one or more times,
        ?-optional and 
        \\D-non digit ch*/
        Matcher matcher = SEGMENT_PATTERN.matcher(testcase1);
        while (found) {
                    boolean Found = matcher.find();
                    String segment = matcher.group();//representing a number or an operator

                        if (Character.isDigit(segment.toCharArray()[0])) {
                            //is digit
                        }
                        else {
                            //is operator

                        }
                    }
```

This a a solution using a patter to determine if you have a number or and operator,u just have to adapt it a little to your case to computing the result.

```
You can add all the matches found to an array list than traverse it and test the operators and computer the result.
```

It works for floating numbers too,ex:"it matches 5.10".

Comment: `//is operator`? What about decimals?

Comment: \\d-means digit,\\.-point,+-one or more times,?-optional and \\D-non digit ch

Comment: @TudorR Perhaps you missed the "without using API" part in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different logic for your purpose.

Usually the logic behind programs algorithms is not different from the logic that you will apply if you have to do the task by hand.

For an expression like your example you would usually do:

1. Find all the *
2. For each * compute the result of the operation
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for + and -

Comment: And how to compute for * operation? I have made a code that calculates string containing +/- but real problem is *

Comment: For every * you have two operands: one at the right of the * and one at the left. A simple strategy could be get all the digit at the left until you encounter a non-digit, then  do the same for the digit at the right (here is important to check for the - sign). <br /> Example "21*-3" you have * at position 2, the left operant goes from position 0 to 1, while the right from 3 to 4. The rest is just math

Comment: If you've seen my code I have tried doing the same ie. getting the left and right numbers and multiplying them (and what I have not done but want to do is calculate 21*3 inside the string and replace it with 63).

Comment: Try with something like string.substring(0, beginLeft-1)+"result"+string.substring(endRight+1, string.length-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a recursive descent parser, a tutorial depicting how a calculator can be implemented (in Python but the same concepts apply to java) can be found here http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-70-python-lines-by-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser/